# Running python scripts with subprocess in windows. Python code checker wrappers from the emacswiki yield the same error

Tags: python, emacs, cmd, subprocess

So i'm trying to setup the python code checkers suggested in the emacs wiki. However, I'm unable to run those scripts in my command shell let alone emacs.
The section is found here:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc7
And I tried the script located [here](https://github.com/tavisrudd/pylint_etc_wrapper/blob/master/pylint_etc_wrapper.py) and [here](http://bitbucket.org/jek/sandbox/src/tip/pycheckers)

In both cases I changed the first line from #!usr/bin python with the full path of my python executable and when I run the scripts via

```
python pylint_etc_wrappers.py someModule.py
```

or

```
python pycheckers.py soemModule.py
```

both boil down to the same error, most likely because they try to open a subprocess. Here's the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pycheckers.py", line 254, in <module>
    runner.run(source_file)
  File "pycheckers.py", line 91, in run
    process = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\devel\Python\Python-2.7\Lib\subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\devel\Python\Python-2.7\Lib\subprocess.py", line 882, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The second script suggests to change the first line to the path of the interpreter (which I did) and to change the path in the main function which looks something like :

```
os.environ['PATH'] = \
      path.dirname(sys.executable) + ':' + os.environ['PATH']
```

which was a bit unclear to me. Any ideas?

Comment: At a guess, you need to make sure that `pylint` etc. are on your path.

Comment: they are in the <Python Root>\Scripts directory which I have added to the system path. I don't think this is the issue. Would be interesting if someone could duplicate these errors on a Win machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pylint 0.25.1, installed using easy_install (Python 2.7, Win XP). Both **pylint** and **pylint.bat** were installed in Python27/Scripts (this directory is in my PATH).

I too get the "The system cannot find the file specified" error when running the **pylint_etc_wrapper.py** script unchanged.

Running pylint from the script does work if

```
command = 'pylint'
```

is changed to

```
command = 'pylint.bat'
```

Another way to make it work is to add `shell=True` to the `Popen()` call.

I can't really explain all this, but there is an unresolved Python bug that looks like it might be relevant: http://bugs.python.org/issue8557.

Comment: that did it! i had to do the same for pyflakes and changed the command to pyflakes.bat