# Python Code checkers wrapper in emacs does not properly feed the results to flymake on win32

Tags: python, emacs, flymake, python-mode

So i'm using this wrapper suggested on the emacs python wiki (found [here](https://github.com/tavisrudd/pylint_etc_wrapper/blob/master/pylint_etc_wrapper.py)) around pep8, pyflakes and pylint which works on the command line (after the trouble of getting it setup on windows according to " [Running python scripts with subprocess in windows. Python code checker wrappers from the emacswiki yield the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434981/running-python-scripts-with-subprocess-in-windows-python-code-checker-wrappers) ".

However, in emacs, flymake will underline the line having an error but when I hover the mouse, the box that should contain the error message is empty. My init file contains:

```
 (setq pycodechecker "etcwrapper.bat")
(when (load "flymake" t)
   (load-library "flymake-cursor")
   (defun dss/flymake-pycodecheck-init ()
     (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                        'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
            (local-file (file-relative-name
                         temp-file
                         (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
       (list pycodechecker (list local-file))))
   (add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
                '("\\.py\\'" dss/flymake-pycodecheck-init)))
```

etcwraper.bat is a simple batch script that runs python on the python wrapper script. I put it in a directory in my system path for convenience. 
Also can I make flymake underline only one character rather than the whole line?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python expert, and have never used it on windows, so this answer may not be useful... but I know there's a hack in some versions of `flymake-cursor` to cope with the fact that `pyflakes` either doesn't report errors correctly for compile errors, or that they're in the wrong format for `flymake` to parse.

You can see the attempted fix for it in my fork of `flymake-cursor` here:

https://github.com/illusori/emacs-flymake-cursor/blob/master/flymake-cursor.el#L126

I got that fix from the Dino Chiesa version, so I don't know the full backstory, but it sounds like that's the issue you're having.

A more recent version of `flymake-cursor` such as mine or Dino's may help you see an error indicator in the emacs message area, but the mouse overlay is handled in `flymake` which has no fixes for this issue as far as I'm aware.

If you provide the output generated by your etcwrapper.bat when run manually, I might be able to help further.

Underlining just one character is also tricky, from my understanding you'd need to redefine `flymake-make-overlay` from `flymake.el` and create two overlays instead of one. You may just find it easier to customize the face for `flymake-errline` and `flymake-warnline` to something less intrusive than underline.

Sorry that neither of these answers are a fix. :)

Comment: Yea this isn't the case I tried your suggestion but it's still the same behavior.